# How to have color errors AND launch into the ipython debugger after an error when starting from the command line?

Tags: debugging, ipython

Vanilla python allows you to do:

```
python -m pdb -c c myscript.py
```

Is there a way to do this with IPython?

```
ipython -i myscript.py
```

almost does the correct thing except it just launches IPython and not IPython %debug.

I want the equivalent of IPython %pdb but from the command line. There is likely a flag I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I missed it:

```
ipython -i --pdb ./bibupdate.py mylibrary.bib
```

-m pdb does not do this.